# Bash: Special characters lost when reading file

Tags: bash, escaping

I have a file containing some Latex :

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{logo.pdf}
 \caption{Example of a pdf file inclusion}
 \label{fig:pdfexample}
\end{figure}
```

I want to read it in a bash script :

```
while read line
  do
    echo $line
  done < "my.tex"
```

The output is

```
begin{figure}[ht]
centering
includegraphics[scale=0.15]{logo.pdf}
caption{Example of a pdf file inclusion}
label{fig:pdfexample}
```

Why did I lose the backslashes and initial spaces ?

How to preserve them ?

Comment: What are you doing to each line that requires you to read it line-by-line? Right now, of course, you could replace the while loop with `cat my.tex`.

Comment: I actually check what is on each line because I want to keep a part of the file between two special "tags".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You lost the backslashes and spaces because bash (via its read builtin) is evaluating the value of the text - substituting variables, looking for escape characters (tab, newline), etc.  See [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) for some details.  Also, echo will combine whitespace.

As far as preserving them, I'm not sure you can.  You'd probably get the backslashes back by doing:

```
while read -r line
  do
    echo $line
  done < "my.tex"
```

which should modify read to not try to evaluate the backslashes.  It will probably still swallow the leading spaces, though.

Edit: setting the `$IFS` special variable to the empty string, like this:

```
export IFS=
```

will cause the spaces to be preserved in this case.

Comment: Quoting `$line` should also preserve the spaces.

Comment: @chepner - that's what I thought; certainly if there were spaces in `$line` that's true, but it turned out that (on my system) they were getting stripped by `read`, before being put into `$line`.

Comment: You can temporarily set IFS during the read command only, so it doesn't affect the rest of the script: `while IFS= read -r line; ...`

Comment: `-r` should almost always be used with `read` (it should have been the default).

Comment: Just to be clear, the documentation (search for "read [-ers]" in the manpage linked) doesn't say anything about substituting variables in `read`'s input. If that were true, I'd expect it to be a source of security vulnerabilities on par with SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `perl` for part or all of your script requirements?

```
perl -lne 'print;' my.tex
```

If you must later shell-out to some other tool, you might still have a problem, unless you can pass the required data in a file.