# Not reading the first character of every second line in a file

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

In a BASH script (latest Xubuntu) this successfully reads and prints every line in mp4.txt

```
ls *.mp4 > mp4.txt
while read F ; do
    echo $F
    echo ${F/mp4}mkv
#        ffmpeg -i "$F" -map 0 -c copy "${F/mp4}mkv"
done < ./mp4.txt
```

Uncommenting the ffmpeg line causes the first character from every other line in mp4.txt to not be in F.

I'm expecting every file line to be read consistently.

I've tried [Bash: Special characters lost when reading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564778/bash-special-characters-lost-when-reading-file)

Comment: `ffmpeg ` seems to be reading from standard input, "stealing" the characters.

Comment: It sounds like `ffmpeg` is reading a byte from stdin. Perhaps you can redirect stdin with `ffmpeg ... < /dev/null`.